# DropzoneJs with basic php form

Tags: php, dropzone

I need to post form inputs and upload img same form.

**php form**

```
<form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Add Image DropzoneJs</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="yorum_name" placeholder="Nickname" name ="yorum_name">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id ="yorum_title" name ="yorum_title" placeholder="Title" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="yorum_text" id="yorum_text"  placeholder="Text..."></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="dropzone" id="myDropzone" name="yorum_img" id="yorum_img"></div>

        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" name="yorumekle" type="submit" id="submit-all"> upload </button>

    </form>
```

**custom.js file**

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myDropzone", { url: "upload.php"});
```

**upload.php file**

```
<?php

print_r($_POST['yorumekle']);
exit;

if(!empty($_FILES)){
    // Include the database configuration file
    require 'dbConfig.php';

    // File path configuration
    $targetDir = "uploads/";
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $targetFilePath = $targetDir.$fileName;

    // Upload file to server
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetFilePath)){

        if (isset($_POST['yorumekle'])) {

            $kaydet=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO yorum SET

            yorum_title = :yorum_title,
            yorum_img = :yorum_img,
            yorum_text = :yorum_text,
            yorum_name = :yorum_name

            ");

            $insert=$kaydet->execute(array(
            'yorum_title' => $_POST['yorum_title'],
            'yorum_img' => $_POST['yorum_img'],
            'yorum_text' => $_POST['yorum_text'],
            'yorum_name' => $_POST['yorum_name']

            ));
         }
        // Insert file information in the database
        $insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO files (file_name, uploaded_on) VALUES ('".$fileName."', NOW())");
    }
}
?>
```

I add to  tag jquery library & dropzone libraries. If you know more simply way to do this or another library like dropzoneJs i will try.

custom js not working know please help me.

Comment: custom js not working  it's a little bit generic. what type of error do you get?

Comment: i can't post image url data & text fields... I try to insert mysql database all the data.